# Reply to particular comments on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

A post was made by popular non-profit organization. Many comments were made on it. Some how replies to certain comments were made. When and how does Facebook allow for replies to particular comments, is it only for organizations?

Answer (score 1):

This was something added to Facebook pages a little while back and it is the choice of the page admin (not the individual replier) about where the feature is turned on or not.

If you own/manage a Facebook **Page** then you used to be able to change this setting by going to Page Settings, but they have now removed it.

Seems that they will soon be enabling it, without the option to turn it off, for everyone.

**Read More**

- [Improving Conversations on Facebook with Replies](https://www.facebook.com/notes/journalists-on-facebook/improving-conversations-on-facebook-with-replies/578890718789613)
- [Facebook Help: How do I turn off replies to comments on my Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10153348707329829)
- [Facebook Help: How do I allow replies to comments on my page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10153028949618238)